# Access header files outside of current c++ file scope

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to set up a simple c++ project with CMake. I am trying to include `Logger.h` header residing under the `utils` folder from `a/A.cpp` file. Currently, I cannot configure my `A.cpp` file access `utils/Logger.h` header file. I have both `A.cpp` and `Logger.h` files in the executable in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, and added `utils` folder to be included directory for the executable
`target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE utils a)` but still I can't access `Logger.h` file. I get `a/A.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'utils/Logger.cpp' file not found`

1. Do I need to add CMakeLists.txt to each subdirectory, one for each `a` and `utils`?
2. Can't I have just one parent that manages what files I can include for each file?
3. I want to have absolute path access from `a.cpp` #include "utils/Logger.h", how to obtain that?

Here is what my folder structure looks like

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── a
│   └── A.cpp
├── main.cpp
└── utils
    └── Logger.h
```

a/A.cpp

```
#include "utils/Logger.cpp"

class A {
public:
  void hello_a() {
    Logger logger;
    logger.print();
  }
}
```

utils/Logger.h

```
#include "iostream"

class Logger {
public:
  void print() { std::cout << "hello from Logger" << std::endl; }
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
project(MyProject)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp a/A.cpp utils/Logger.cppo)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE utils a)
```

Comment: "Do I need to add CMakeLists.txt to each subdirectory, one for each `a` and `utils`?" - No, for being able to include the file via `#include <utils/Logger.h>` you need to add only a directory, against which one could resolve given **relative path**. As you can see, a directory `a` does fit for that purpose: there is no file at the path `a/utils/Logger.h`. Similarly, `utils` directory doesn't fit to: the path `utils/utils/Logger.h` refers to non-existent path. Only **root directory** of your project (in CMake - `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`)  fits: it contains `utils/Logger.h`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So how can I resolve the relative path of a subdirectory (from `A.cpp`) to an absolute path starting from the root directory?

Comment: `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` always refers to the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes in C++ use paths relative to the include directories (or the source file in case you use includes with `""`-quotes).

For

```
#include "utils/Logger.cpp"
```

to work in `a/A.cpp` either there needs to be a file `a/utils/Logger.cpp` or the top directory needs to be one of the include directories.

To achieve the latter, you can simply do

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE .)
```

in addition to including the header instead of the source file. Note that for public/interface headers of exported targets you need to replace `.`, but in case of private headers it doesn't matter.

---

A note on `#include ""` vs `#include <>` though: When encountering the `""` version, usually compilers look for a file relative to the source file and if not found they do  same lookup as for the `<>` version. For this reason you'll never see

```
#include "iostream"
```

in any examples and I strongly recommend not making a habit of including standard library headers using the `""` version of `#include`.

---

Furthermore including a `.cpp` usually indicates an error; Avoid the necessity to do this, if you're tempted to create a program like this or at the very least document this clearly in the code. Include the header not the source.

Comment: Thanks @fabian `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE .)` and adding the utils to the linking directory were what I needed.